# Custom Web Receiver to Cast HLS AES-128 encrypted content?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to add Google Cast support into my existing audio app.
Content is streamed via hls protocol and is AES-128 encrypted. Do i need to provide my Custom Web Receiver in order to playback the content or Default Media Web Receiver should be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Default Media Web Receiver is enough. It is clearly mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#delivery_methods_and_adaptive_streaming_protocols